# how can i loop this code to make a pattern?

Tags: python, loops, repeat, python-turtle

***I have an assignment to create a tile pattern. I finished the pattern, but I am struggling to get the code to repeat. I need to be able to run it with the following specs:

```
column_ct=10,row_ct=10
column_ct=16,row_ct=9
column_ct=100,row_ct=100
```

with column_ct and row_ct referring to the number of columns and rows respectively.
my code is pretty simple as I am very new to coding.
If someone could give me advice on how to implement my code into a loop, I would be very grateful.
Here is my code:***

```
import turtle


def tile():
    t = turtle.Turtle()

    t.fillcolor("black")
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(20)
    t.end_fill()

    t.penup()
    t.back(30)
    t.fillcolor("red")
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(50)
    t.end_fill()

    t.penup()
    t.back(50)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(100)  # Forward turtle by 100 units
    t.left(90)  # Turn turtle by 90 degree
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)

column_ct= 10

row_ct=10

def tile_repeat (column_ct, row_ct,):
    for r in range(row_ct):
        for y in range(column_ct):
            tile()
            t.penup()
            t.forward(100)
            t.pendown



tile_repeat(10, 10)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: each of those are different variable to use I don't think that you would need to repeat the code use call the same function with those variables instead.

Comment: What is supposed to be happening? Can you give more context into what you think needs to be repeated?

Comment: You already provided your code, but in this case it would be helpful to provide an image or description of what result you were actually expecting. The result currently looks like a black circle in the lower right corner of a larger square with a width of 2.5 times the circle diameter, partially overlapped by a red circle with a diameter that's the same as the square width, centered in the square. How would that extend to a larger pattern?

Comment: @Grismar yes, its really strange I know. It is supposed to be a lady bug. I want to repeat the entire thing into a grid pattern, like a checkerboard or something. I should probably draw it out like you said

Comment: @AndrewRyan the code is supposed to make two circles within a square. I want to repeat this entire image in a grid pattern

Answer (score 0):

To loop the pattern into a grid shape you can do:

```
def tile_repeat (column_ct, row_ct,):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    for r in range(row_ct):
        for y in range(column_ct):
            tile(t) # passing the turtle object to the function
            t.penup()
            t.forward(180)
            t.pendown()
        # return to left most part of drawings
        t.penup()
        t.right(180)
        t.forward(100*column_ct)
        # go down one row
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(100 )
        t.left(90)
        t.pendown()

tile_repeat(3, 3)
turtle.done()
```

Using this you have to pass the t variable to your function

```
def tile(t):
```

and remove the

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

inside of tile()